# Replacing columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has 80 columns. I want to replace some random columns with different values. I found some solution where we use df["c"] = mylist. but what if i want to randomly select a column and i don't know the column name. Something like, `colNum = 12`, and then i do `df[colNum] = mylist`. Here is the code i tried but with no luck:

```
def poisonData(data):
    newValues = []
    for i in range(6):
        colNum = np.random.randint(0,81)
        temp=data.iloc[:,colNum]
        for x in temp:
            newValues.append(float(x*colNum))
        se = pd.Series(newValues)
        data.columns[colNum] = se.values
    return data
```

i also tried `data.iloc[:,colNum] = se.values`. I can't find what i am doing wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) and then `.iloc` to select any column without duplicates:

```
>>> index_of_random_cols = random.sample(range(len(df.columns)), 6)
>>> df.iloc[:, index_of_random_cols]
```

Then, you could fill these columns using a numpy array of random values:

```
... = np.random.rand(len(df.index), 6)
```

---

Resulting code:

```
>>> N_cols = 6
>>> index_of_random_cols = random.sample(range(len(df.columns)), 6)
>>> df.iloc[:, index_of_random_cols] = index_of_random_cols * np.random.rand(len(df.index), N_cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to randomly select `N` columns:

```
N = 3
cols = np.random.choice(df.columns, size=N, replace=False)
```

Then, to loop:

```
for col in columns: 
    df[col] # do something
```

or with a vectorial function:

```
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(something)

# OR

df[cols] = func(df[cols])
```